# XML to XML with XSLT using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt, reporting-services

I am trying to modify the structure of an XML file using an XSLT.
The below is the input XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <table1>
        <Detail_Collection>
            <Details ID="1   " Type="4"  />
            <Details ID="2   " Type="5"  />
        </Detail_Collection>
    </table1>
</Report>
```

This is the XSLT file which I created however it is not picking up the values from the input XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"
    >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>TEST</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Report/table1/Detail_Collection/Details">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that no vaues are being picked up and I cannot understand what is the problem.  It seems like the input XML is not being linked with the XSLT. After this is solved I should be able to do my task since I think I grasped the basics of XSLT elements (e.g. for-each, value-of, sort etc.)  However since I'm new to XSLT I am finding a hard time to connect/input the XML into the XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your XML has an `table1` element which have missed out in your `xsl:for-each` select. It should look like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Report/table1/Detail_Collection/Details">
```

Secondly you are doing `<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>` to get the values of the Details, but `ID` is an attribute in your XML, so you really need to use the `@` symbol to indicate this

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"    >

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>TEST</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Report/table1/Detail_Collection/Details">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine.  How do you get the values if the required XML out structure is similar to this:-  < Detalis  ID = " "  Type=" "  />.  If I place the <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/> between the double quotes it won't work.

Comment: You need to use "Attribute Value Templates" here. You would do something like `<Details ID="{@ID}" />`. Note the use of curly braces.

Comment: Thank you Tim.  This was a good kick start for me and I'm doing a lot of progress in the task I need to accomplish.  I am now able to format an XML to XML.  I'll now need to figure out how to include validation (using an XSD) and finally obtain the output XML directly from a Reporting Service project when I click the export button and "XML file with report data) in the .rdl project.  Do let me know If you know of any good sources or guidelines how to accomplish this. Thanks again.